# Trying to find a vampire book from 90s/2000s about a girl who works at her parents' cafe in a seaside town

Tags: story-identification, young-adult, vampire, female-characters

Me and my sister can remember reading a YA vampire book from when we were younger, but it's evading us; a girl who works at her parents' cafe in a seaside town, someone asks her parents if she can 'come out to play', there was a cave party? At some point, definitely cliffs involved, maybe vampire hunters? Sorry it's very vague, but it's killing us.

Comment: So was the girl a vampire? Were her parents? The other people at a cave party?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Answer (score 3):

Was googling keywords to try and find the name of a book from my childhood and came across this 2 year old post. I've since found the book I was looking for and I suspect it's the one you were looking for too. If you're still looking for it, it's called **Room 13** by Robert Swindells. This is the summary from [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0440864658):

> There is no room thirteen in the creepy Crow's Nest Hotel, where Fliss and her friends are staying on a school trip. Or is there? For at the stroke of midnight, something peculiar happens to the door of the linen cupboard next to room l2. And something is happening to Ellie-May Sunderland, too - something very sinister. Somebody was in there. Somebody - or some thing...

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You could improve this answer by editing it to explain why you think this might be the correct book, i.e. the ways in which it matches the one described in the question.